# how to write no data found in oracle forms

Tags: oracleforms

I am using below code to find string. If entered string not matched then cursor is pointing at last record. But i have to display message "No data found".

```
BEGIN
IF :BLOCK.DESC IS NULL THEN
     ERR_MESSAGE('Please enter  name OR  Description...');       
     SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('BLOCK.DESC',ENABLED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
     GO_ITEM('BLOCK.DESC');
ELSE 
   BEGIN
         GO_BLOCK('CCC_MST');
         FIRST_RECORD;           
         LOOP
             IF   :CCC_MST.DESC like '%'||:BLOCK.DESC||'%' 
                 OR :CCC_MST.CC LIKE '%'||:BLOCK.DESC||'%' THEN
                EXIT;                
             END IF;
             NEXT_RECORD;                
             EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD='TRUE'; 
       END LOOP;           
   END; 

 END IF;
END;
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer..

```
 if ...then
  v_counter:=count+1;
 end if;

end loop;
 if v_counter<1 then
    message('no data found');
 end if;
```